# How can i fix my image modal button

Tags: css, asp.net

In my application, I have image modal i placed that one in header tag in that i have label. In between label and image modal i have some space. When i run application the page appears it will sit in fixed position but label message is occurs image modal button is moving some distance but label message is not appear that time image modal come near to label. How can i change styles with and without label message is occurs or not i need to fix the position. How can i do this one please tell me.

Code:

```html
<h2>Ready To Do:&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
               &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <img id="myImg" src="image.png" /> </h2><br />
```

Style.css

```css
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;   
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}
```

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0H0l.png)
Thank you

Comment: I cant catch what you need, can you add some image to show us what you want please? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Facundo-la-rocca, I added my image please see once

Comment: Is [this](http://codepen.io/facundo_larocca/pen/oBNOWy) what you are looking for?

Comment: My image modal changes the position it is not a fixed position when label message is not appear it changes the position. when label message appears it fit in position

Comment: Take a look again, it is an example, you should style it better of course. To try it remove (or add) the label tag

Answer (score 0):

Your problem mainly stems from the fact that you're using `&nbsp;` for spacing.

For solving spacing you should always, always use CSS, and never rely on `&nbsp;`.

I would recommend you attempt to restructure this by containing it inside a block element, for example a `div` instead of an `h2` tag.

Something like the below would be far better, though it's just the start:

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
  <h2>Ready to...</h2>
  <img src="https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}

h2 {
  float: left;
}

img {
  float: right;
  height: 40px
}
```

In all honesty I recommend going through layout arrangement using CSS, there's many resources out there. Hope this helps.